# Getting a list of Doctrine Entities (UI population, access rights, etc.)

Tags: php, inheritance, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to get a hang of Doctrine Entities and their inheritance model. Here's a situation I'd like some advice on; I have a base class `Box`, and depending on the application, several other classes can extend the `Box` class (STI), such as: `TextBox`, `ImageBox`, `SliderBox`, etc. `PortraitBox` could extend `ImageBox`, and so on.

What would be the best way to get a list (in an automated way) of all classes that extend `Box`? For an example, if app's users need to choose which Box to create, or an admin needs to choose all Boxes that should be editable for certain users, and so on.

In case of UI population, is there an alternative to populating the UI elements with class names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to define all possible values in a **configuration file**. With that you don't have to implement a sophisticated auto-discovery that will fail as soon as requirements change and you can even supply additional information. Consider this example:

boxes.yml

```
boxes:
    text:
        class: "My\FQCN\To\TextBox"
        displayName: "Text Box"
        editableBy: ["admin", "editor"]

    image:
        class: "My\FQCN\To\ImageBox"
        displayName: "Image Box"
        editableBy: ["admin", "photographer"]

    ...
```

Now, you'll just need to implement the domain logic so your application understands the configurations file. And don't forget to document the different configuration possibilities somewhere.

If you need the access control to be dynamic, fine: use the second-level identifiers (e.g. `text` or `image`) as keys to identify the boxes in your database and assign the rights. Those are the unique internal names, regardless of UI and actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @FaKeller. Reading your answer got me thinking of an idea how this could be automated using console commands when adding new box types.